# How to download profile image?

Tags: 8.1, people

There is an entry in the People (contact entry) and it has a profile image set. The original profile image has been lost and I would like to get hold of that image.

I searched on the Live online People entry, but this profile does not have any image.

Also when I click to Edit the contact I can see this image exists inside Profile Images directory.

How do I go to Profile Images directory?  Or how can I download this image?

Windows Phone 8.1 is on the phone.

Comment: just take a screenshot of the image and crop it

Comment: Quality is too bad. That's why I wanted access to the image directly.